# область прокрутки для ВСЕХ виджетов в CUSTOMtkinter

Tags: tkinter, scrollview

как сделать область похожей на то, как мы делаем с
CTk.frame только там где колесиком мыши можно прокручивать и виджеты будут перемещаться?

Может кто делал и есть пример или опять же гидхаб?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, элемент Frame является не прокручиваемым.

Для достижения нужных целей приходится использовать некоторые костыли.

Самый лучший костыль:

1. Создаем Canvas
2. К нему привязываем ttk.Scrollbar
3. В Canvas кладем Frame
4. В последний фрейм кладем нужное нам...

Вот пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(50):
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Sample scrolling label").pack()

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А можно прокрут осуществить через колёсико мышки?

Comment: Если попробывать через бинд только

Comment: Если ты хочешь прокручивать именно фрейм, то и так и сяк его невозможно крутить

Comment: Если тебе нужно просто убрать из виду сам скрол, а его функционал оставить, то придутся использовать сторонние модули, направленные для работы c tkinter

Comment: Крч, ты, наверное, понял что tkinter не для казуалов (и это плохо). Сегодня эта библиотека из коробки дается для понятия как работают почти все GUI-модули. Как только интуитивно разобрался в нем, сразу же иди на другие библиотеки.

Comment: Например? Может Qt?

Comment: Но зато у Custom Tkinter современный дизайн... Хех

Comment: Присмотрись к PyQt, там и интерфейс можно строить визуально, а не как здесь кодом

Comment: Я который уже почти написалл фулл програму закзчику. ЛОЛ

Comment: PyQt по сравнению с Custom Tkinter и не такое может...